# Count prime results of polynomial

Tags: python, primes, polynomials

Can someone help me and tell me why this doesn't work? The goal is to count the number of prime numbers that are produced by a given polynomial for inputs n in a specified range [a,b]:

```
    def count_primes(poly, a, b):
    primes = 0
    if b >= a:
        for n in range(a, b):
            result = poly(n)
            if result > 1:
                for i in range(2, result):
                    if (result % i) == 0:
                        break
                    else:
                        primes += 1
            else:
                break
    return primes


def poly(n):
    return n**2 + n + 41


print(count_primes(poly, 0, 39))
```

The result should return 40 in this case.

[2] Problem Solution
Step-1. Take in the number to be checked and store it in a variable.
Step-2. Initialize the count variable to 0.
Step-3. Let the for loop range from 2 to half of the number (excluding 1 and the number itself).
Step-4. Then find the number of divisors using the if statement and increment the count variable each time.
Step-5. If the number of divisors is lesser than or equal to 0, the number is prime.
Step-6. Print the final result.
Step-7. Exit.

Comment: Your code thinks 7 counts as 5 primes, one for each tested divisor it's not divisible by.

Comment: Note that sieveing works with any *polynomial* congruence. That is, p(x + kN) = p(x) mod N if p(x) is a polynomial in x with integer coefficients. Taking advantage of this can save you significant time if b-a is large, or if a is very large.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to count primes:

```
        if result > 1:
            for i in range(2, result):
                if (result % i) == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    primes += 1
```

Should be:

```
        if result > 1:
            isPrime = True
            for i in range(2, result):
                if (result % i) == 0:
                    isPrime = False
                    break
            if isPrime:
                primes += 1
```

Also, it goes without saying.  Easy optimizations for prime number detection. You only have to test for divisibility divisibility with 2 and all odd numbers between 3 and sqrt(result).

Comment: BTW, `for ... else ...` could be a better choice.

Comment: Just to mention: in Python 3.8 there is now math.isqrt() which returns integer part of square root.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `else` clause in the nested loop refers to the `if`, when it should be activated only if the loop finished without `break`. Just change the identitation to:

```
if result > 1:
    for i in range(2, result):
        if (result % i) == 0:
            break
    else:
        primes += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_primes(poly, a, b):
    primes = 0
    if b >= a:
        for n in range(a, b+1):
            result = poly(n)
            if result > 1:
                for i in range(2, result):
                    if (result % i) == 0:
                        break
                else:
                    primes += 1
            else:
                break
    return primes


def poly(n):
    return n**2 + n + 41


print(count_primes(poly, 0, 39))
```

Problems:

1. you do `primes += 1` too early. In your methods, you have to test until no possible division happens, then do the addition.
2. `[a, b]` The endpoints are both inclusive. Then you should use `b+1` at your `for n in range(a, b+1)`, which produces `40`.